# Beamer: Footnote vertical align problem

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

The usual trick to get rid of the Beamer navigation symbols and replace them only by a page number is to use

```
% Make footline contain only page/pages
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}
```

However, when I use it in this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
% Make footline contain only page/pages
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\begin{frame}{Hello}
Hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

the page number floats vertically partially outside the page:
[image]

**How should I fix the vertical alignment?**

Answer (score 1):

The fix is very straight-forward. Move

```
% Make footline contain only page/pages
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}
```

outside the `document` block. I.e., the fixed MWE would become

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Make footline contain only page/pages
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello}
Hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is now properly vertically aligned:
[image]